# Silverlight / RIA Services / EF - Custom Objects

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, ria

I've been searching all over the net for a way to address my issue and I haven't had any luck.  I am developing a Silverlight business class app and trying to make use of RIA Services.  I am successfully loading and saving entities without any major problems however I have a need to load what I call "value lists" when my application first loads.

My value lists are independent entities, probably 5 or so, that are made up of Id's (keys) and Value's and they are used to populate things like combobox's and autocompletebox's. I can query each one individually however I'd rather load all the value lists at once in one single query to speed things up since each one has less than 15 records.  I tried developing a custom class to return all of them and it looks something like this...

```
<DataContract(IsReference:=True)>
<KnownType(GetType(ValueList1Item))>
<KnownType(GetType(ValueList2Item))>
<KnownType(GetType(ValueList3Item))>
Partial Public Class ValueLists

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ValueList1 AS List(Of ValueList1Item)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ValueList2 AS List(Of ValueList2Item)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property ValueList3 AS List(Of ValueList3Item)
End Class
```

And I've tried numerous ways to implement the service method, one of which looks something like this...

```
Public Function GetValueLists() As ValueLists
        Dim ret As ValueLists = New ValueLists

        ret.ValueList1 = (From v1 In ObjectContext.ValueList1Items
                          Select v1).ToList

        ret.ValueList2 = (From v2 In ObjectContext.ValueList1Items
                          Select v2).ToList

        ret.ValueList3 = (From v3 In ObjectContext.ValueList3Items
                          Select v3).ToList

        Return ret
    End Function
```

I've also tried returning an IQueryable(Of ValueLists).  No matter what I've tried, whenever I try to use my custom type it fails to expose the method to the client.  Is it even possible to do something like this with RIA Services or has it yet to mature?  I know I've done this in the past with straight WCF however it is obviously more work.

Thanks in advance,
Casey

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for my bad english)

I tried this before and it really does not work. If you create a new class for `ValueList1`, it work. But if you use an class with the `[Key]` attribute, for some reason, its not generated  (the property won't appear on client side). So one solution would be to create classes like ReadOnlyValueList1 and return it:

```
ret.ValueList1 = (from v1 In ObjectContext.ValueList1Items
                      select new ReadOnlyValueList1()
                       {
                           Prop1 = v1.Prop1,
                           Prop2 = v1.Prop2,
                       }).ToList();
```

(sorry, C# code, probably this is a little different in VB)

It make sense anyway since you do not want all the EF stuff (tracking, etc) just to bind some lists and combos.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Leo. As soon as I get a chance I'll give that a try and see if it works.  I may end up dumping RIA Services pretty soon and go straight to a regular WCF implementation if I continue to run into problems like this.  I know WCF is more work however it's certainly a lot more flexible which is nice.  At this point I get the impression that RIA Services is not the best solution for applications with a fairly high level of complexity but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: Well I've yet to have any luck with this Leo. I really don't want the entities to be read only as I will have a "System" page where the user can edit these value lists.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without issue, but when passing an object to the RIA services client, *you need to specify a [Key] which is guaranteed to be unique between all like objects.* This is due to the way that RIA services handles caching those objects on the client side. Also, your ValueList1Item, ValueList2Item, and so on *need to be serializable*.

When set up this way, RIA services will make your server POCO objects into client Entity objects. The only issue you will run into here is you have to manually handle any CUD operations. If it's read-only data you're passing into the client, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: As recommended Derreck I added the Key attribute to the Id property of the DTO which is just a random generated number.  While it did compile correctly this time it still doesn't transmit the data according to fiddler. I think at this point I'm going to dump RIA services and go for a standard WCF implementation.  Yes it will take longer to develop however the flexibility is a lot better and I already understand WCF so in the end it will probably go smoother and possibly even quicker. So far I am not a fan of IQueryable and I know with WCF I can use lists with no problems.

Comment: If you're using that method, I wouldn't bother using IQueryables. Just use arrays or lists. It's not easy to get it working, so I can understand your frustration. I've been using RIA services for over a year now and there are a lot of things that need to be worked on in my opinion. If you happen to give it another shot using arrays or lists instead of IQueryable, let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have managed to get a little closer.  Adding Key to the Id property of the return object at least made it compile successfully however using fiddler to see the results I can see there is nothing in the object.  I'm guessing this is some sort of serialization issue at this point.

I constructed my return object (dto) from a copy of another entity class generated from my model to ensure I didn't miss anything.  I then commented out all the change tracking to make sure it wasn't causing any problems. Here's the class:

```
<DataContract(IsReference:=True)> _
<KnownType(GetType(ValueList1Item))> _
<KnownType(GetType(ValueList2Item))> _
Partial Public Class ValueLists

#Region "Primitive Properties"

    <DataMember()> _
    <Key()> _
    Public Property Id() As Long
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Long)
            If Not Equals(_id, value) Then
                _id = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _id As Long



    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ValueList1() As List(Of ValueList1Item)
        Get
            Return _valueList1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of ValueList1Item))
            If Not Equals(_valueList1, value) Then                
                _valueList1 = value               
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _valueList1 As List(Of ValueList1Item)



    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ValueList2() As List(Of ValueList2Item)
        Get
            Return _valueList2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of ValueList2Item))
            If Not Equals(_valueList2, value) Then                
                _valueList2 = value               
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _valueList2 As List(Of ValueList2Item)

#End Region
End Class
```

And the method I'm using to construct and return the object looks like this...

```
    Public Function GetValueLists() As ValueLists
        Dim ret As ValueLists = New ValueLists

        ret.Id = RandomNumber(1, 100000000)

        ret.ValueList1 = (From vli1 In ObjectContext.ValueList1Items
                                 Select vli1).ToList()

        ret.ValueList2 = (From vli2 In ObjectContext.ValueList2Items
                                      Select vli2).ToList()


        Return ret
    End Function
```

Tracing this method shows it is in fact working fine.  I can see all the value list items populated properly, it just never leaves the server.  This leads me to believe it's some sort of serialization issue at this point.